# filter query on specific field in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, http-post, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a document like this

```
  {
    _index: "logstash-2015.11.30",
    _type: "hadoopgeneric",
    _id: "AVFVsF6ypMu_z_qvIUgL",
    _score: null,
    _source: {
             @timestamp: "2015-11-30T00:00:00.017Z",
             message: "selector : 48 - Element found for using multiple selectors using query .js-product-brand.product-brand",
             @version: "1",
             host: "ip-x-x-x-x",
             path: "/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr",
             type: "hadoopgeneric",
             thread_id: "15119",
             thread_name: "MainThread",
             component_name: "Page",
             severity: "DEBUG",
             env: "STG",
             role: "spider",
             ip: "x.x.x.x",
             tags: [
                 "processed"
             ]
            },
   }
```

I have to filter those documents that have path `/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr` in it (in `path` field particular)

I tried this general search query `http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?pretty=true&q="/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr"&sort=@timestamp&size=100000`

Its giving me the result but now I am thinking of trying to search only in `path` field by firing this query like this (I am getting no results in this query) -- `http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?pretty=true&q="path: /logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr"&sort=@timestamp&size=100000`

I was going through this document [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html?q=term) on elastic search. But I am not sure how to pass such queries as post parameter in elastic search. I am using python library to make a post request to elastic search

Below is what I have tried so far

```
esurl = http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search
r = requests.post(esurl,data={"term":{'path':'/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr'}})
r.text
```

`{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[5D_RNDQPRf6xyLO1suIoCA][logstash-2015.11.30][0]: RemoteTransportException[[ip-x-x-x-x-elkstorage][inet[/x.x.x.x:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.11.30][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]; }{[o8jLb8P5SWOfsCo78eUlHg][logstash-2015.12.01][0]: RemoteTransportException[[ip-x-x-x-x-elkstorage][inet[/x.x.x.x:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.12.01][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent];}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The q parameter seems to be wrong (the `"` character is in wrong position), try this:

```
http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?pretty=true&q=path:"/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr"&sort=@timestamp&size=100000
```

On the other hand,the term query is valid but it must be within `query` key, something like:

```
import requests
import json

esurl = "http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search"
r = requests.post(esurl,data=json.dumps({"query": {"term":{'path':'/logs/stats/container/application_1448508514184_0178/container_e06_1448508514184_0178_01_003568/stderr'}}}))
r.text
```

Comment: This answer is partially accepted for the 1st part.... Still getting the same error for firing query through requests library.

Comment: Edited! You basically have to send a serialised json as the post body. Could you test again please?

Answer (score 0):

Correctly building queries for Elasticsearch's DSL is a pain. its just so easy to get it wrong. For most usecases I just use either the query-builder in the Head plugin - or the SQL-to-ES plugin.

Both provide a simple UI for generating queries - and you can convert the result to json and just use that in your code.

This requires some work to install, but if you need to formulate lots of ES queries, it really pays off.

[head plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) - does alot more than just building queries.

[sql plugin](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql)